# C#, How to unescape characters in JObject values?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, escaping

I have some Javascript code embedded in some JSON fields.

For example:

```
{
  "elements": [{
    "bindingParams": "return field.innerHTML.match(/\\d+/gi).toString();\n"
  }]
}
```

And I want to write this code to a new file. The thing is that when this Javascript is set as a value to a JObject the newlines and other characters as the backslash are being escaped.

I have tried using `Regex.Unescape(field.Value<string>())`, but I get an error in fields with `\\d`

The error is `parsing 'field.innerHTML.match(/\\d+/gi).toString();' - Unrecognized escape sequence \\d.`

I could always go with `field.Value<string>().Replace("\\n", "\n).Replace("\\","\").Etc(...)` but I don't know the sequences that Newtonsoft JObject is escaping.

I would like to know the escape characters that Newtonsoft uses or a method/function from Newtosoft that allows me to unescape the string.

I appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could help, though I've not used this before - https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_StringEscapeHandling.htm

Answer (score 0):

The double backslash "\\d" is causing the problem.

Before parsing the jsonString try to replace them this way:

```
var jsonString ="{\"elements\": [{\"bindingParams\": \"return field.innerHTML.match(/\\d+/gi).toString();\n\"}]}";
jsonString  = jsonString .Replace("\\", "\\\\"); // <=== this line
var o = JObject.Parse(jsonString); // This works !
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue was that I was trying to unescape an already unescaped string.

The `field.Value<string>()` already unescapes the string.  So the solution to my issue was just not to call `Regex.Unescape`and use the value directly.

Sorry.